# Tensor Product problem.

Tags: vector-spaces, modules, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\Bbb F$, and let $x\not=0,y\not=0 $ be two elements in $V$.

I want to show that $x\otimes_{_F} y=y\otimes_{_F} x$ iff $x=ay$ where $a\in \Bbb F$.

I know the second direction, so only want to see the first direction (If case).

Comment: If $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is a basis for $V$ what is a basis for the tensor product? Have you tried using this to solve your problem?

Comment: So the "if" case is $\Leftarrow$, and the "only if" case is $\Rightarrow$. I don't know about others, but the "first" direction seems to be the $\Rightarrow$ case. Asking about "if/onlyif" directions is a lot better than this "first/second" code, but really it would be best if you just *clearly wrote the question in terms of the one direction you wanted to see*. It looks like if you don't do this, there are a lot of opportunities to ask about the wrong direction, and for the reader to answer the wrong direction. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for such $x,y\neq 0$, you want to show $x\otimes y=y\otimes x$ in $V\otimes_F V$ **if** $x=ay$ for some $a\in F$.

Then $x\otimes y=ay\otimes y=y\otimes ay=y\otimes x$.

Since this seems by far to be the easier half of the problem, I am beginning to wonder if you meant to ask about the other direction.

Suppose $x,y$ are linearly independent. As such, this pair can be extended with other elements of $V$ to form a basis $\beta$ of $V$. We know that given a basis $\{b_i\mid i\in I\}$ for $V$, we automatically have a basis $\{b_i\otimes b_j\mid i,j\in I\}$ for $V\otimes_F V$.

Applying this to our basis $\beta$, we have that $x\otimes y$ and $y\otimes x$ are linearly independent elements of a basis of $V\otimes_F V$, and so certainly $x\otimes y\neq y\otimes x$.

By proving the contrapositive, we've shown that if $x\otimes y=y\otimes x$, then $x,y$ are linearly dependent, hence $x=ay$ for some $a\in F$.

Answer (score 2):

Take a set of basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of $V$ and let $x=\sum_
{i}x^ie_i,~y=\sum_
{j}y^je_j$, then
$$x\otimes y=\sum_
{i,j}(x^ie_i)\otimes(y^je_j)=\sum_
{i,j}x^iy^je_i\otimes e_j$$
$$y\otimes x=\sum_
{i,j}y^jx^ie_j\otimes e_i$$
The symmetry implies
$$x^iy^j=x^jy^i$$
That is,
$$\frac{x^i}{y^i}=\frac{x^j}{y^j}=a$$
for some constant $a$.

Comment: What are $x^i, y^i$?

Comment: @MatHeMatCian The $i$-th component of vector